# The parameter panel to modify primitives is greyed out

Tags: interface

[image]

The black pencil lines show where I am talking about, the panel is translucent and does not allow any clicking?

In the image I provided above I marked the area where now I cannot change the vertices of any new primitives I add in blender 2.79, everything else works but this area is now grayed out and doesn't do anything when clicked?

Comment: Are you in the correct mode? Is one object selected?

Comment: U hit the nail on the head! Thanks so very much for such a prompt reply, the problem was an add-on called "Crack it", I was using it last night and the problem occurred this morning and UR answer solved the problem. I just disabled it for now and reported the bug to the developer. :)